Is there a difference between adding a source file and linking to a static library?
I know that all compilation files (translation units) are compiled down to object files, and then the linker resolves symbols that the compiler couldn't find at the compilation stage by looking in those object files. But this is also what happens when linking to a static library. So what are the differences between linking to a precompiled static library versus linking to an object file. I have a roughly 300k line c file (sqlite) and I'm wondering whether I should compile that to a static library rather than just passing the c file to the compiler as a compilation unit. I know in both cases the compiler doesn't 'see' the code in that file until the link stage. I think one time when I was experimenting with this stuff I saw a difference in final binary size, but I can't remember if I had the optimization settings set properly (ie., function-level linking -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections).

A library is just a collection of object files. LIbraries are used for functions that are going to be used by many different applications, so you don't have to duplicate them for each application.

Libraries are just a collection of object files.  Advantage: compile once use in many projects.  Disadvantage: need to make sure the compilation options between all libraries and application(s) are compatible.

the compiler doesn't 'see' the code in that file until the link stage. The compiler has done with it by then.

Libraries also allow for dynamic linking. So the library code doesn't have to be copied into the executable. And dynamic linking typically uses shared memory, so all the processes using the same library are sharing the same memory mapping to the object file.

The answer as usual, it depends. You are saving compilation time by using static library, but (theoretically) for every project configuration you will need to create a separate static library. You also miss the full program optimization that is done during linkage because compiler can't see the code. And finally, (theoretically) for every new compiler version you need to recompile the libraries. So, unless compile time is critical I would just have all sources to be compiled with the executable, moreover compiler knows when to recompile the obj files and won't do it unless necessary.

@Barmar, yes, libraries are also used for dynamic linking, but of course this is a different kind of library than is used for static linking, with differently built contents.

For me, there is one importance difference: passing an object file to the linker command line usually forces the object to be linked into the binary, while an object inside a static library (which is really just an archive) is only linked if there is a dependency to it.

The title question asks about adding a source file, but the question body asks instead about linking a standalone object file (vs. linking to a library containing that object file).  These are not equivalent: both alternatives considered in the question body seem to assume that the relevant source file is included in the project.

Advantage if using source code: You can use Macros for conditional compiling. I use it for variants, product or debug, enabling extended logging and more.


what are the differences between linking to a precompiled static library versus linking to an object file.

Supposing all else is equal, there is zero difference between the result obtained by linking a standalone object file and the result obtained by linking an identical object file drawn from a static library.
The main purposes of static libraries are

to avoid unnecessary recompilation
to package related object files together in a more easily reusable unit

Of course, the first can also be achieved simply by keeping built object files around.  If we're talking about something intended for use only within a single project then keeping the object files is simpler, and reuse is not a consideration.
There may be organizational advantages to static libraries in certain build systems, but that's a fairly special case, which you would recognize if it were relevant to you.

Would LTO behave the same way (or it is covered in the last paragraph)?

I expect so, @EugeneSh., but it's hard to find confirmation.

One advantage of using a library over an object file is that the object file will be linked unconditionally but the same file in a library will only be linked if the code is used.  Most of the time, that makes no difference — you will be using the code in the object file.  But if the code might be conditionally used, a library might be better.

Agreed, @JonathanLeffler, and that does not conflict with this answer.  Also, although that's a consideration in general, I do not think it is a concern to the OP of this question, who seems to be trying to decide whether to put an object file they know they need to link into a library.
